# Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 Cannot execute /bin/bash/: Not a directory how to fix?

Tags: bash, digital-ocean

I use digital portal hosting, and I put the project there for jango, i go through this instruction

```
$ sudo groupadd --system webapps
$ sudo useradd --system --gid webapps --shell /bin/bash --home /webapps/new_studio_app new_studio

$ sudo mkdir -p /webapps/new_studio_app/
$ sudo chown new_studio /webapps/new_studio_app/
```

and then i try to login to this user

> new_studio

```
root@new-studio:~# sudo su - new_studio
Cannot execute /bin/bash/: Not a directory
```

Comment: how does the line corresponding to user new_studio look in /etc/passwd file?

Comment: new_studio:x:999:999::/webapps/new_studio_app:/bin/bash/

Comment: ...and the trailing `/` after bash doesn't seem suspicious?

Comment: Just remove the trailing `/` and retry?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to ubuntu and do not know much, I'm working on Windows) and how to remove this sign? And save the changes? If you know the answer, please complete it as an answer and I will accept it if it works, and add you + 1 to the rating!

Comment: Something like `sudo nano /etc/passwd`; it's a simple editor: follow instructions on screen. You simply delete the offeding "/".

Comment: or use `chsh` command..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, it seems that there is an extra `/` in the shell for `new_studio` user. Just run below command and you should be good:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash new_studio
```

This command will set `/bin/bash` as shell to `new_studio` user.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I LOVE YOU!